# Equivalent for specific php preg_replace in javascript

Tags: php, javascript, preg-replace

Is there equivalent for this specific php preg replace in JS?

```
preg_replace('/[\n]{2,}/', "\n", "Hi,\nHow are you?\n\n\nI am just testing");
```

Thank you!

Comment: Did you search on Google or StackOverflow? Regex are practically the same across languages you just need to search on how to use regex with JS. Kinda lazy question I'd say...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's basically the same, though you have to provide the `g` flag:

```
var theString = "Hi,\nHow are you?\n\n\nI am just testing";

theString = theString.replace(/\n{2,}/g, '\n');
```